# MathGL/C++ Starter Program undefined references

Tags: c++, makefile, undefined-reference, msys2, mathgl

I'm having an issue getting the MathGL example program to compile. It is failing during linking. I am using MSYS2 in the Mingw64 environment on Win10/64.

The error:

```
$ make
g++ -o test test.o
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
: test.o:test.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `__imp_mgl_create_graph'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
: test.o:test.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__imp_mgl_fplot'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
: test.o:test.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `__imp_mgl_write_frame'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
: test.o:test.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `__imp_mgl_delete_graph'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: test] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS= -I. -lmgl -lodbc

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

test: test.o
    $(CC) -o test test.o
```

Code:

```
#include <mgl2/mgl_cf.h>

int main(void) {

    HMGL gr = mgl_create_graph(600,400);
    mgl_fplot(gr,"sin(pi*x)","","");
    mgl_write_frame(gr,"test.png","");
    mgl_delete_graph(gr);

    return 0;

};
```

Comment: You need to use `CFLAGS` when creating the executable, or at least the `-lxxx` flags from it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks @RetiredNinja !

Comment: It's not right to put linker flags into `CFLAGS`.  `CFLAGS` is for the compiler.  I'm surprised you don't get warnings from the compiler about unused arguments.  You should put libraries to be linked into the `LDLIBS` variable (anyway, that's the standard variable used for this; you can call it whatever you like of course).

Comment: Appreciate the note on standards for makefiles, I'll update my code! Still learning some of this stuff. Thanks!